# How can I open a main form from multiple forms (and vice versa) and keep the same instance?

Tags: c#

I have a main form that has multiple buttons on it that will allow a user to open other forms.  Each of these forms has a button on them that will allow the user to return back to the main form.  How can I do this so that they are all part of the same instance?  Since my main Program.cs file is a static file, I thought that if I instantiated the main form in my Program.cs file like this:

```
static class Program
{
    P90xScheduleForm ScheduleObjectForm = new P90xScheduleForm();
```

that I would be able to access the main form from the other forms like this:

```
 private void btnGoToSchedule_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     ScheduleObjectForm.Show();
     this.Hide();
 }
```

but I get an "The name 'ScheduleObjectForm' does not exist in the current context" error.  I also tried adding "public static" in front of the instantiation statement in the Program.cs file but that didn't help.

I'm at a loss of what to do.  Trying to instantiate the main form in each of the sub-forms creates new instances.

Maybe I'm just getting too far ahead of myself.  This is beyond where we are in class but I was hoping that if I got adventurous and started making my own programs (in addition to my homework of course) that it would help me understand things better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not the way you do it. I assume it's winforms.
You have to instantiate one of the forms(the main form) firs.

Then when you click some of it's buttons you can show other forms like this.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        new Form2().ShowDialog();
    }
```

When you've shown the second form you can 'go back' to the main form by closing it.

Once you close the main form your app will exit.

Comment: Yes, but if you instantiate the main form in each and every one of the sub forms then you get new instances.  I've already been there and done that.  I tried instantiating the main form in my Program.cs file and then used your example in the main form and get an "The type or namespace name 'ScheduleObjectForm' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)" error

Comment: In my example the button1_Click handler is for the main form. Just use the code generated by VS - Application.Run(new Form1()); there is no need to access the main form from other forms.

Comment: Ok, I got it to work going from the main form to the sub form, but if I use the same approach going from the sub-form back to the main, then new instances will be created.  And I do need to be able to go back and forth between the main forms and subforms

Comment: you just close the sub-form and that's how you 'get back' to the main form ;-) that's how all windows apps work - it's not user friendly to close the window that contains a button and then show it back, if that's what you're trying to do

Answer (score 0):

I think you probably need to make the static class program public:

```
public static class Program 
{
     ....
```

Comment: I just did that but it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, Program.cs file already contains following line that instantiates main form that gets created at the time of project creation, if it was present in your program then change Form1 with your Main form's name:

```
    Application.Run(new Form1());
```

While opening other forms, set their parent to main form using their Owner property:

```
    frmOther.Owner = this;
    frmOther.Show();
    this.Hide();
```

To show Main form from other forms:

```
    this.Owner.Show();
    this.Hide();
```